# Display images with change when refresh

Tags: php

```
<?php
$sql1= mysql_query("SELCT * FROM adds ORDER BY adds_id DESC ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){?> 
    <tr>
        <td width="134" valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;">
              <?php echo $row['image_name'];?>
        </td>
```

when I use this code I able to display a single image, but I want to display an image with refresh, means when user refresh - a new image will display.

Can this will be happen with `rand()` or need to any JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY

```
<?php
$sql1= mysql_query("SELCT * FROM adds ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){?> 
    <tr>
        <td width="134" valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;">
        <?php if(!empty($row['image_name']))  { ?>
           <img src="images/thumbs/thumb_<?php echo $row['image_name'];?>" />
        <?php } else { 
           echo "text wahatever";
         ?>
        </td>
```

Comment: thanks dear can you tell me one more thing i using two <td> one for image and other text. if image will not be there then text will display in full td.if text not avaliable then image will be display in full td. thanks

Comment: @naresh why two `td` u can use with one ..if sometime text and image both appear then  have to use two td otherwise no need         see my update

Comment: <img src='images/thumbs/thumb_<?php echo (empty($row['image_name'])) ? : $row['adds'];?>' width="80" height="80" />

Comment: when i use this <img src='images/thumbs/thumb_<?php echo (empty($row['image_name'])) ? : $row['adds'];?>' width="80" height="80" /> it will not working

Comment: tell me first how to vote. nd tell me one more thing i want to check both image and text available or ot if text is not there then the image will dispay and if image will no not then the text will diaplay in hole <td>

Comment: @naresh just use the logic... dont be dependent

Answer (score 3):

Your WHILE loop is looping over all the rows,and echoing the last row's image.
The required change in your code can be to modify your query little bit:

```
   Select * from adds order by rand() limit 1;
```

This will select only 1 row,which is random from the data set. You do not need to iterate over everything if you do not need that data. And it will display a random image as required.

Answer (score 0):

For a really simple fix, change your query to `ORDER BY RAND()` perhaps?